# Restore Database Removing existing object from Database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups, database-restore

I have 1 database name **abc** and its backup is **abc.bak**

but **abc** has the following tables

**1) xyz
2) cdf**

but backup has only 1 table **"xyz"**,

So, when I am restoring **bak** file it will automatically remove **cdf** from the database,
Is there any way to restor **xyz and keep cdf as it is?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. If you restore a backup you are restoring the database to that point in time. That is what backups do. Sounds like what you want *isn't* a back up, but some kind of migration script.

Comment: You could restore the backup to a different database name and then copy the desired objects and data into the abc database.

Comment: Yes I thought as much, BTW thank you